# Is it likely to receive more token airdrops to one of the original Ethereum addresses from the crowdsale?

Tags: addresses, crowdsale, airdrop

Is it likely to receive more token airdrops to one of the original Ethereum addresses from the crowdsale?

Hi there,

I participated in the original Ethereum crowdsale and I used to store a certain amount of ETH on that address.

I still have the address but now it's rather empty.

I used to receive airdrops ever so often but ever since I emptied that account it seems like the airdrops are coming less frequently.

Is it a good idea to keep storing ETH on an address which participated in the original crowdsale? Does that increase the chances of airdrops, compared to storing value in say DAI on a non-original crowdsale ETH address?

Vesa

Answer (score 0):

Airdrops are usually (but not always) based on eth balance at some snapshot. Say I wanted to release a token called ARD (Airdrop) today, I'd probably take a snapshot of eth balances on block 7296300 (a block today) and drop ARD proportional to each account's ETH balance. So if I airdrop 10 ARD per ETH, an account with 10 ETH would get 100 ARD, and an account with 1 ETH would get 10 ARD. As long as you still hold the ETH at some account, you should still get airdrops at the new account holding it.

Also, I'm not sure, but I believe the number of airdrops happening has dropped considerably since 2017 when there were a ton of ICOs/airdrops